# codes still execute after promise reject

Tags: javascript

I have the following codes:

```
function promise3() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        function1().then(() => {
            resolve();
        }).catch(err => {
            reject(err);
            console.log("after error");
        });  
    })
} 

promise3().catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

`function1` returns a promise. But when `function1` fails and returns an error. I see the `console.log("after error")` before the console.log of the error. I though the codes after `reject` would not run. `reject` acts like a return. What is happening here then?

Comment: Of course? `reject()` is just a function call, it doesn't do anything beyond that. If you want code execution to end when you trigger resolve or reject, `return` them, to terminate the promise function immediately.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to execute anything after resolve/reject you need to return them as follow.

```
 function promise3() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            function1().then(() => (
                resolve(); //change the brackets to () instead of {}
            )).catch(err => {
                return reject(err); //put a return keyword in front
                console.log("after error");
            });  
        })
    } 
    
    
    promise3().catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

`()`: mean that you are returning that is inside.
`{}`: mean that you need to do the following tasks and return nothing if there is no return statement.